# Swift Property Wrapper on Struct

Tags: json, swift, property-wrapper

I am struggling to create a swift struct, where I can use a property wrapper to decode some JSON that sometimes requires a value to conform to a specific type, but other times may become a dictionary with a store ID reference.

Here is an example struct:

```
struct JobDetail: Codable {
    var title: String
    var years: Int
}

struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
    var job: JobDetail
}

struct Employee: Codable {
    @UUIDEmbedded var info: Person
}
```

For example, in the `Employee` struct above, I can assign a unique ID to the info variable - I can also decide not to, in which case, the ID would just default to nil. In JSON form, it could look like either of the following...

```
{
  "info": {"id": "068D61D7-9BA9-4459-B328-1FF801F52264", "value": {"name": "John", "age": 30, "job": {"title": "CEO", "years": 5}}}
}
```

or

```
{
  "info": {"name": "John", "age": 30, "job": {"title": "CEO", "years": 5}}
}
```

While the code I currently have works great for this kind of thing and can automatically distinguish a "info" variable with an ID, from one without an ID, the problem occurs when I try to then use this property wrapper on anything other than a custom struct. For example, if I want to give the "age" variable in `Person` the `@UUIDEmbedded` property wrapper.

```
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String              //works with UUIDEmbedded: ❌
    @UUIDEmbedded var age: Int    //works with UUIDEmbedded: ❌
    var job: JobDetail            //works with UUIDEmbedded: ✅
}
```

> ⚠️ Error: typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "info", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "value", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "age", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found number instead.", underlyingError: nil))

❌ Doesn't work for JSON:

```
{
  "info": {"name": "John", "age": 30, "job": {"title": "CEO", "years": 5}}
}
```

✅ Does work for JSON:

```
{
    "info": {"name": "John", "age": {"id": "884D61D7-9BA9-4459-B328-1FF801F52264", "value": 30}, "job": {"title": "CEO", "years": 5}}
}
```

***It should be working for both.***

Thank you for all of you help in advance!

## Current Code

**Property Wrapper**

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UUIDEmbedded<T: Codable>: Codable {
    private var value: T
    private var id: UUID?

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get { value }
        set { value = newValue }
    }

    var projectedValue: UUID? {
        get { id }
        set { id = newValue }
    }

    init(wrappedValue: T) {
        self.value = wrappedValue
    }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        if container.contains(.id) {
            if let idString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id) {
                self.id = UUID(uuidString: idString)
            }
        }
        
        if container.contains(.value) {
            self.value = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .value)
        } else {
            // If value key is not found, decode the entire container as the value
            self.value = try T(from: decoder)
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let id = id {
            try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        }
        try container.encode(value, forKey: .value)
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id
        case value
    }
}
```

**Decoding**

```
let jsonStringWithoutID = """
{
  "info": {"name": "John", "age": 30, "job": {"title": "CEO", "years": 5}}
}
"""

do {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    // Decoding JSON without ID
    let decodedStructWithoutID = try decoder.decode(Employee.self, from: Data(jsonStringWithoutID.utf8))
    print(decodedStructWithoutID.info.name) // Output: John
    if let uuid = decodedStructWithoutID.$info {
        print(uuid) // Output: nil
    } else {
        print("UUID is nil")
    }
    print(decodedStructWithoutID.info.age)
    print(decodedStructWithoutID.info.job.title)
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

Comment: That error you showed originates from `try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)`. You need to catch it, and try decoding a single value instead with `try decoder.singleValueContainer()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `decoder.singleValueContainer()` to determine if the value is a single fundamental type (String, Int, Boolean, etc.). Otherwise, catch custom structs and or `@UUIDEmbedded` *key-value pairs* using the `container<CodingKey>(keyedBy type: CodingKey.Type)` decoder method.

Here is the code that needs to be implemented...

```
do {
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    self.value = try container.decode(T.self)
} catch {
    //Original code here
}
```

Altogether, the decoder for the property wrapper would look like this...

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    do {
        let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
        self.value = try container.decode(T.self)
    } catch {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
        if container.contains(.id) {
            if let idString = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .id) {
                self.id = UUID(uuidString: idString)
            }
        }
        
        if container.contains(.value) {
            self.value = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .value)
        } else {
            // If value key is not found, decode the entire container as the value
            self.value = try T(from: decoder)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You start by assuming there is a keyed container:

```
let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
```

In the case of single values, this is not the case.

I'd suggest trying to decode as a `{id: ..., value: ...}` first, then if any part of that process fails, try decoding it as a `T`. This way, you avoid decoding many `T`s that also happen to have `id` and `value` keys, as a UUID-value pair.

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    do {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        id = try container.decodeIfPresent(UUID.self, forKey: .id)
        self.value = try container.decode(T.self, forKey: .value)
    } catch { // if anything goes wrong, try just decoding the value
        self.value = try T(from: decoder)
    }
}
```